# Showing highlight effect when mouse hovered over list element by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have the following code:

```js
function main() {
    
    $("li").hover(function() {
        $(this).effect("highlight");
    });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="list">
        <li>Thing 1</li>
        <li>Thing 2</li>
        <li>Thing 3</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically what I want it to accomplish is to do the highlight effect (http://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/) when the mouse is hovered over any of the list elements (Thing 1, Thing 2, Thing 3). For some reason this doesn't work the way I do it. Could someone explain me why this code doesn't work and how it should be done then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the library for jQuery ui,

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/vnfvcp5h/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="list">
        <li>Thing 1</li>
        <li>Thing 2</li>
        <li>Thing 3</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And you don't need to wrap your code in a function and call in on document ready, you can simply add the event listener

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").hover(function () {
        $(this).effect("highlight");
    });
});
```

Comment: What is buggy? The jQuery ui highlight effect?

Comment: The code you present is not buggy, it could just be a jqui thing but moving your mouse over the items it looks like its having a seizure.

Answer (score 1):

"highlight" effect requires jQuery UI to be loaded too.

Look at example at http://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/

Answer (score 1):

try some another way to highlight.

create a class in css which contains the effect of highlight you want and then try this

> $('li').hover(function(){
>       $(this).addClass("highlight");
>   
> },function(){
>       $(this).removeClass("highlight");
>   });
>   
>   .highlight{
>   background: #222;
>   color: #fff;
>   }